# Installing php5-fpm on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: nginx, php

My web server is running Ubuntu 10.04. I want to use PHP in conjunction with nginx. However, the php5-fpm extension cannot be installed because it is not part of the repositories.

My question:

On launchpad I see several options such as this one:

https://launchpad.net/~brianmercer/+archive/php

Which one should I choose for a live system?

EDIT: Is there maybe an official version that I could use because it was included in the repositories in later Ubuntu versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirments, BTW following is the basic configuration and suits well most of the time.

```
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   backend;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone in the same situation, here's how I did it in the end:

you need the python-software-properties for the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

now you can add the nginx repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/php5
```

update everything..

```
sudo apt-get update
```

.. and you are ready to install php5-fpm

```
sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Now you need to use the config provided by S Rakesh:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   backend;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
    fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
```

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/php5 : Error: can't find signing_key_fingerprint at https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~nginx/+archive/php5`